# No SIP packets from virtual client machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, asterisk, sip, wireshark

Implementing a SIP call using asterisk server, but every time I have one client call another (virtual machines), Wireshark doesn't show any SIP packet requests even though the call is being placed?

Answer (score 0):

1) check firewalls on both machine, try turn firewall off

2) check sip nat settings or assign public ips to hosts.

3) check network availible inside your virtulization environment(each host can ping other one).